# Why concurrent using `printf()` not causing overflow?

Tags: c++, multithreading, overflow

I'm doing some experiments on `printf()`, my code is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
 
void foo() 
{
    while(1) printf("a");
}

void bar()
{
  while(1) printf("b");
}

int main() 
{
  std::thread first (foo);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()
  std::thread second (bar);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0)
  first.join();                // pauses until first finishes
  second.join();               // pauses until second finishes
  return 0;
}
```

A lot of ab will output. But I have a question here: as far as I know, printf has a buffer, so why `buffer[pos++]` will cause no overflow? I guess a circle buffer is used, but I'm not sure.

So when the buffer is not full, two threads will write to the buffer concurrently, I also write another version

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
 
void foo() 
{
    while(1) printf("aaaaaa");
}

void bar()
{
  while(1) printf("bbbbbb");
}

int main() 
{
  std::thread first (foo);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()
  std::thread second (bar);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0)
  first.join();                // pauses until first finishes
  second.join();               // pauses until second finishes
  return 0;
}
```

But the output will not something like `ababab`, I wonder how printf deal with writing concurrently?

Comment: `buffer[pos++]` ?? The buffer is used to buffer output before it is flushed to the screen. Once you see it on the screen there is no need to keep it in the buffer anymore

Comment: Your assumption that the buffer of `printf` would be full and overflow at some point would mean that _any_ program would have a fixed limit of text it could output, which is not the case. You probably assume that the buffer would only be printed when you output a new line? This would be a horrible bug in the `printf` implementation.

Comment: Why would concurrent printing be more susceptible to buffer overflow?

Comment: @wohlstad No, when the buffer is full, it is flushed.

Comment: I meant the display buffer in the console/terminal where `stdout` is actually writing. Maybe it's not relevant, I admit the question wasn't 100% clear to me.

Comment: @wohlstad The output buffer resides in the process, not in whatever standard output happens to be attached to at the moment (which isn't necessarily a tty).

Answer (score 3):

> so why buffer[pos++] will cause no overflow?

The implementation of `printf` takes care that it never writes outside of its buffer in case that it uses a buffer.

> I guess a circle buffer is used

The implementation may choose to do so.

> I wonder how printf deal with writing concurrently?

The C standard says:

> Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.